# How would I be able to automate recording surrounding audio several times a day, daily, for 5 minutes at a time?

Tags: microphone, software, recording

So basically, during school, in my 5 minute breaks between classes, I have been bullied and ridiculed. Thus, I am trying to find a way to automate capturing evidence of this. Now, my local (Manitoba) laws dictate that so long as I am a party to the conversation and not in a place with expectation of privacy (like a bathroom), I may record. As I am the one being made fun of, directed at me, not to their friends, I am a party to it, I need to find the following:

A way to record sound 3 times a day, each day, for 5 minutes at a time using either shortcuts (my testing proved not sufficient in doing that though) or a third party app (that does not share any recordings)

Comment: You never mentioned your device.  Is it a Mac or an iPad?  Now, while I'm not a lawyer, and I am not at all familiar with Canadian law, to be party of something is to have direct involvement/interaction.  Asking a question here (like you did) makes you a party.  If I posted something about you, but not directly to you doesn't necessarily make you a party.  That said, depending on the context, you may or may not have *standing* if  damages case can be established. Talk to a laywer.

Comment: tbh, if the phone/pad is in a pocket or bag, no-ones is going to be able to hear anything anyone said anyway. If you're going to hold it out in free air, you may as well just switch it on manually.